# Getting access to a Epson TSE via /dev/ttyUSBx

Tags: python, usb, wireshark

I have problems to get access to my

usb 1-1.2: Product: TSE USB stick

it is recocniced as

usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected

For windows there is a driver so it's possible to connect to it on COM3.

Using the usual connect code it's not possible to write/read to the device.

```
import usb.core
import usb.util


dev=usb.core.find(idVendor=0x04b8, idProduct=0x0638)

print(dev)


if dev.is_kernel_driver_active(0x0):
    try:
        dev.detach_kernel_driver(0x0)
    except usb.core.USBError as e:
        sys.exit("Could not detatch kernel driver from interface({0}): {1}".format(i, str(e)))

dev.set_configuration()

msg = '<open_device><device_id>local_TSE</device_id><data><type>type_storage</type></data></open_device>\0\0'
print(msg)

print(dev.write(0x1, msg))
ret = dev.read(0x81, 512, 100000)
```

This results in:

```
DEVICE ID 04b8:0638 on Bus 001 Address 007 =================
 bLength                :   0x12 (18 bytes)
 bDescriptorType        :    0x1 Device
 bcdUSB                 :  0x200 USB 2.0
 bDeviceClass           :    0x0 Specified at interface
 bDeviceSubClass        :    0x0
 bDeviceProtocol        :    0x0
 bMaxPacketSize0        :   0x40 (64 bytes)
 idVendor               : 0x04b8
 idProduct              : 0x0638
 bcdDevice              :  0x100 Device 1.0
 iManufacturer          :    0x2 EPSON
 iProduct               :    0x3 TSE USB stick
 iSerialNumber          :    0x1 60202253FD0000FD
 bNumConfigurations     :    0x1
  CONFIGURATION 1: 100 mA ==================================
   bLength              :    0x9 (9 bytes)
   bDescriptorType      :    0x2 Configuration
   wTotalLength         :   0x20 (32 bytes)
   bNumInterfaces       :    0x1
   bConfigurationValue  :    0x1
   iConfiguration       :    0x0 
   bmAttributes         :   0x80 Bus Powered
   bMaxPower            :   0x32 (100 mA)
    INTERFACE 0: Mass Storage ==============================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x0
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x2
     bInterfaceClass    :    0x8 Mass Storage
     bInterfaceSubClass :    0x6
     bInterfaceProtocol :   0x50
     iInterface         :    0x0 
      ENDPOINT 0x81: Bulk IN ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :  0x200 (512 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x0
      ENDPOINT 0x1: Bulk OUT ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :    0x1 OUT
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :  0x200 (512 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x0

<open_device><device_id>local_TSE</device_id><data><type>type_storage</type></data></open_device>
99
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mareike/Doag/mvo_pos/test/tse_connect_test.py", line 47, in <module>
    ret = dev.read(0x81, 512, 100000)
  File "/home/mareike/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/usb/core.py", line 1029, in read
    ret = fn(
  File "/home/mareike/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 846, in bulk_read
    return self.__read(self.lib.libusb_bulk_transfer,
  File "/home/mareike/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 954, in __read
    _check(retval)
  File "/home/mareike/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/usb/backend/libusb1.py", line 604, in _check
    raise USBError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret])
usb.core.USBError: [Errno 32] Pipe error
```

How is it possible to force linux to reconize the nano-USB-stick on /dev/ttyUSB* and not as mass-storage?

Output from Wireshark - USB

```
14737   2022-09-20 22:16:23,622982  host    1.10.0  USB 36  GET DESCRIPTOR Request DEVICE
14738   2022-09-20 22:16:23,623116  1.10.0  host    USB 46  GET DESCRIPTOR Response DEVICE
14739   2022-09-20 22:16:23,623131  host    1.10.0  USB 36  GET DESCRIPTOR Request CONFIGURATION
14740   2022-09-20 22:16:23,623268  1.10.0  host    USB 37  GET DESCRIPTOR Response CONFIGURATION
14741   2022-09-20 22:16:23,623281  host    1.10.0  USB 36  GET DESCRIPTOR Request CONFIGURATION
14742   2022-09-20 22:16:23,623393  1.10.0  host    USB 60  GET DESCRIPTOR Response CONFIGURATION
14743   2022-09-20 22:16:23,623404  host    1.10.0  USB 36  GET DESCRIPTOR Request STRING
14744   2022-09-20 22:16:23,623517  1.10.0  host    USB 30  GET DESCRIPTOR Response STRING[Malformed Packet]
14745   2022-09-20 22:16:23,623531  host    1.10.0  USB 36  GET DESCRIPTOR Request STRING
14746   2022-09-20 22:16:23,623624  1.10.0  host    USB 32  GET DESCRIPTOR Response STRING
14747   2022-09-20 22:16:23,623641  host    1.10.0  USB 36  GET DESCRIPTOR Request STRING
14748   2022-09-20 22:16:23,623753  1.10.0  host    USB 30  GET DESCRIPTOR Response STRING
14749   2022-09-20 22:16:23,623766  host    1.10.0  USB 36  GET DESCRIPTOR Request STRING
14750   2022-09-20 22:16:23,623879  1.10.0  host    USB 62  GET DESCRIPTOR Response STRING
14751   2022-09-20 22:16:23,624909  host    1.10.0  USB 36  SET CONFIGURATION Request
14752   2022-09-20 22:16:23,625292  1.10.0  host    USB 28  SET CONFIGURATION Response
14753   2022-09-20 22:16:23,625303  host    1.10.0  USB 36  SET INTERFACE Request
14754   2022-09-20 22:16:23,625565  1.10.0  host    USB 28  SET INTERFACE Response
14755   2022-09-20 22:16:23,625577  host    1.10.0  USBMS   36  GET MAX LUN Request
14756   2022-09-20 22:16:23,625692  1.10.0  host    USBMS   29  GET MAX LUN Response
```

Until here all messages are between 1.10.0 and host afterwards 1.10.1 and host

```
14757   2022-09-20 22:16:23,625714  host    1.10.1  USBMS   58  SCSI: Inquiry LUN: 0x00 
14758   2022-09-20 22:16:23,625741  1.10.1  host    USB 27  URB_BULK out
14759   2022-09-20 22:16:23,625742  host    1.10.1  USB 27  URB_BULK in
14760   2022-09-20 22:16:23,656654  1.10.1  host    USBMS   63  SCSI: Data In LUN: 0x00 (Inquiry Response Data) [SCSI transfer limited due to allocation_length too small]
14761   2022-09-20 22:16:23,656669  host    1.10.1  USB 27  URB_BULK in
14762   2022-09-20 22:16:23,656688  1.10.1  host    USBMS   40  SCSI: Response LUN: 0x00 (Inquiry) (Good)
14763   2022-09-20 22:16:23,656715  host    1.10.1  USBMS   58  SCSI: Inquiry LUN: 0x00 
14764   2022-09-20 22:16:23,656757  1.10.1  host    USB 27  URB_BULK out
14765   2022-09-20 22:16:23,656758  host    1.10.1  USB 27  URB_BULK in
```

Set Configuration Request:

```
Frame 14751: 36 bytes on wire (288 bits), 36 bytes captured (288 bits) on interface \\.\USBPcap1, id 0
    Interface id: 0 (\\.\USBPcap1)
        Interface name: \\.\USBPcap1
        Interface description: USBPcap1
    Encapsulation type: USB packets with USBPcap header (152)
    Arrival Time: Sep 20, 2022 22:16:23.624909000 Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1663704983.624909000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.001030000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.001030000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 53.784593000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 14751
    Frame Length: 36 bytes (288 bits)
    Capture Length: 36 bytes (288 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: usb]
USB URB
    [Source: host]
    [Destination: 1.10.0]
    USBPcap pseudoheader length: 28
    IRP ID: 0xffffc307c9d7a010
    IRP USBD_STATUS: USBD_STATUS_SUCCESS (0x00000000)
    URB Function: URB_FUNCTION_SELECT_CONFIGURATION (0x0000)
    IRP information: 0x00, Direction: FDO -> PDO
        0000 000. = Reserved: 0x00
        .... ...0 = Direction: FDO -> PDO (0x0)
    URB bus id: 1
    Device address: 10
    Endpoint: 0x00, Direction: OUT
        0... .... = Direction: OUT (0)
        .... 0000 = Endpoint number: 0
    URB transfer type: URB_CONTROL (0x02)
    Packet Data Length: 8
    [Response in: 14752]
    Control transfer stage: Setup (0)
Setup Data
    bmRequestType: 0x00
        0... .... = Direction: Host-to-device
        .00. .... = Type: Standard (0x0)
        ...0 0000 = Recipient: Device (0x00)
    bRequest: SET CONFIGURATION (9)
    bConfigurationValue: 1
    wIndex: 0 (0x0000)
    wLength: 0
```

Set Interface Request

```
Frame 14753: 36 bytes on wire (288 bits), 36 bytes captured (288 bits) on interface \\.\USBPcap1, id 0
    Interface id: 0 (\\.\USBPcap1)
        Interface name: \\.\USBPcap1
        Interface description: USBPcap1
    Encapsulation type: USB packets with USBPcap header (152)
    Arrival Time: Sep 20, 2022 22:16:23.625303000 Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1663704983.625303000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.000011000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.000011000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 53.784987000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 14753
    Frame Length: 36 bytes (288 bits)
    Capture Length: 36 bytes (288 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: usb]
USB URB
    [Source: host]
    [Destination: 1.10.0]
    USBPcap pseudoheader length: 28
    IRP ID: 0xffffc307c9d7a010
    IRP USBD_STATUS: USBD_STATUS_SUCCESS (0x00000000)
    URB Function: URB_FUNCTION_SELECT_INTERFACE (0x0001)
    IRP information: 0x00, Direction: FDO -> PDO
        0000 000. = Reserved: 0x00
        .... ...0 = Direction: FDO -> PDO (0x0)
    URB bus id: 1
    Device address: 10
    Endpoint: 0x00, Direction: OUT
        0... .... = Direction: OUT (0)
        .... 0000 = Endpoint number: 0
    URB transfer type: URB_CONTROL (0x02)
    Packet Data Length: 8
    [Response in: 14754]
    Control transfer stage: Setup (0)
Setup Data
    bmRequestType: 0x00
        0... .... = Direction: Host-to-device
        .00. .... = Type: Standard (0x0)
        ...0 0000 = Recipient: Device (0x00)
    bRequest: SET INTERFACE (11)
    bAlternateSetting: 0
    wInterface: 0
    wLength: 0
```

Get Max Lun Request

```
Frame 14755: 36 bytes on wire (288 bits), 36 bytes captured (288 bits) on interface \\.\USBPcap1, id 0
    Interface id: 0 (\\.\USBPcap1)
        Interface name: \\.\USBPcap1
        Interface description: USBPcap1
    Encapsulation type: USB packets with USBPcap header (152)
    Arrival Time: Sep 20, 2022 22:16:23.625577000 Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1663704983.625577000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.000012000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.000012000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 53.785261000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 14755
    Frame Length: 36 bytes (288 bits)
    Capture Length: 36 bytes (288 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: usb:usbms]
USB URB
    [Source: host]
    [Destination: 1.10.0]
    USBPcap pseudoheader length: 28
    IRP ID: 0xffffc307c9d7a010
    IRP USBD_STATUS: USBD_STATUS_SUCCESS (0x00000000)
    URB Function: URB_FUNCTION_CLASS_INTERFACE (0x001b)
    IRP information: 0x00, Direction: FDO -> PDO
        0000 000. = Reserved: 0x00
        .... ...0 = Direction: FDO -> PDO (0x0)
    URB bus id: 1
    Device address: 10
    Endpoint: 0x80, Direction: IN
        1... .... = Direction: IN (1)
        .... 0000 = Endpoint number: 0
    URB transfer type: URB_CONTROL (0x02)
    Packet Data Length: 8
    [Response in: 14756]
    Control transfer stage: Setup (0)
    [bInterfaceClass: Mass Storage (0x08)]
Setup Data
    bmRequestType: 0xa1
        1... .... = Direction: Device-to-host
        .01. .... = Type: Class (0x1)
        ...0 0001 = Recipient: Interface (0x01)
    USB Mass Storage
        bRequest: GET MAX LUN (0xfe)
        wValue: 0x0000
        wIndex: 0
        wLength: 1
```

So there are some GET messages. And after the 3 Set messages it's possible the device is changed so it's possible to read/write.

Comment: You mean that there is multi-endpoint device, main of which is USB mass storage that provides a driver for windoze to support real modem on it or so? use `usb-modeswitch` software for that (https://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/). It should be available as an official package in many Linux distros.

Comment: I don't think the vendor/product ID is known by the current usb-modeswitch-data package (2019-11-28). You'll probably need to do some investigation on Windows using Wireshark with USBPCap to work out how it switches the mode from a USB mass storage device to a communications device.

Comment: Thanks pointing out this possibilty. Will try to monitor the windows behavior.